# Mutation observer - get all video tags of childs

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, mutation

I have a mutation observer (subtree: true).
I shows all nodes added (I guess). When I monitor it with console.log(mutation.target.tagName) I see DIV and BODY and so on...
HoweverI I need to add a listener now to all added  tags (in fact one for onPlay and one for onPause)

Any idea how I can find (and react on) all added video tags in the childNodes added?

```
var target = document.body;
//then define a new observer
var bodyObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    //How do i egt the video tags to add a listener?
    console.log("mutation detected: " + mutation.target.tagName);
    if (mutation.target.tagName == "VIDEO") {

        mutation.target.onclick =function () { console.log("The video has been clicked")}
    }
})
})
var bodyObserverConfig = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, 
characterData: true };
bodyObserver.observe(target, bodyObserverConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The added nodes are listed in `addedNodes` property of a `MutationRecord` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) (`mutation` in your case). You have to iterate through this list and search for video nodes.
Here is an example:

If stackoverflow code snippet does not work - try codepen https://codepen.io/bsalex/pen/WMGvry .

```js
var target = document.body;
//then define a new observer
function addVideoHandler(node) {
  if (node.tagName == "VIDEO") {
    node.onclick = function() {
      alert("The video has been clicked");
    };
  }
}
var bodyObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    //How do i egt the video tags to add a listener?
    console.log("mutation detected: " + mutation.target.tagName);
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(addedNode => {
      addVideoHandler(addedNode);
      // it might be text node or comment node which don't have querySelectorAll
      addedNode.querySelectorAll && addedNode.querySelectorAll("video").forEach(addVideoHandler);
    });
  });
});
var bodyObserverConfig = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
};
bodyObserver.observe(target, bodyObserverConfig);

// Example tools code below

document
  .querySelector(".add-videos-here-action")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    const videoElement = document.createElement("video");

    document.querySelector(".add-videos-here").appendChild(videoElement);
  });

document
  .querySelector(".add-nested-videos-here-action")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    const wrappingElement = document.createElement("div");

    wrappingElement.innerHTML =
      "<div><p><video /></p></div><div><video /></div>";

    document.querySelector(".add-videos-here").appendChild(wrappingElement);
  });

document
  .querySelector(".add-not-videos-here-action")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    const notVideoElement = document.createElement("div");
    notVideoElement.textContent = "It is not a video";

    document.querySelector(".add-videos-here").appendChild(notVideoElement);
  });

document
  .querySelector(".add-videos-here-too-action")
  .addEventListener("click", () => {
    const videoElement = document.createElement("video");

    document.querySelector(".add-videos-here-too").appendChild(videoElement);
  });
```

```css
video {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button class="add-videos-here-action">Add video</button>
<button class="add-not-videos-here-action">Add NOT video</button>
<button class="add-videos-here-too-action">Add another video</button>
<div>
  <div class="add-videos-here">
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="add-videos-here-too">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An added node may be a container with video nested inside so you'll need to also enumerate getElementsByTagName on each node.

Comment: First things first: Thank you so much for the reply!
I will have a look into this but if: an element of the addedNodes (mutation) (div) would be another <div> and inside that there would be a video; would I find this?!

Comment: Yes, it is related to @wOxxOm comment. I've updated the answer and pen.

Comment: Stupid question: wouldn't the example add ALL videos, so even the one that have been added before?

Comment: @David We work only on added nodes here. It shouldn't.

Comment: @Bsalex That does the trick!I added onended onplay and on pause and it seems to be working. I will start the tests now! Thank you so much for your support!